# How to draw Sierpinski 4-cycle graphs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, draw

[image: 1[1]]

this is sierprinski 4 cycle graph S(1,C4), S(2,C4), S(3,C4).....and so on. I am trying to make but fail to make. so help me

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Since you have tried something, edit your question and add your code, even if it is not working.

Answer (score 6):

It's almost certainly the case that making the few of these you care about by using basic TikZ commands is the easiest thing to do. E.g., something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle, draw, fill=black] (1) [label=south west:1] at (0,0) {};
    \node[circle, draw, fill=black] (2) [label=north west:2] at (0,1) {};
    \node[circle, draw, fill=black] (3) [label=north east:3] at (1,1) {};
    \node[circle, draw, fill=black] (4) [label=south east:4] at (1,0) {};
    \draw (1) -- (2) -- (3) -- (4) -- (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: S(1, C4)]

But that's kind of boring. So let's do something a little more interesting.

First, [generalized Sierpinski graphs](http://www.renyi.hu/conferences/ec11/posters/parreau.pdf) are pretty neat but they don't really specify a distance between nodes. (By distance, I mean when drawing the graph, not minimum path length between two nodes.) Looking at the figure you provided (which I assume you copied from Gravier et al.), it looks like the four copies of S(k-1,C_4) that make up S(n, C_4) are separated by a distance of n-1. So let's go with that.

The recursive structure lends itself to a recursive solution. So what we'd like to do when drawing S(n, C_4) is the following.

1. Figure out how much to shift each of the four copies of S(n-1, C_4).
2. Determine where to place each label.
3. Draw each of the four S(n-1, C_4), shifted and labeled appropriately.
4. Connect the appropriate nodes in the four copies of S(n-1, C_4).

The first step isn't hard, per se, but does require solving a basic recurrence relation. I'm sure there's an easier way to solve this, but let w(n) be the width of S(n, C_4). Now based on the separation rule derived above, we have the recurrence w(n) = 2*w(n-1) + n - 1 and w(1) = 1.

We can solve this using any standard method (or cheat like I did and use Wolfram|Alpha) to get w(n) = 3*2^(n-1) - n - 1. This gives us the width, but what we really want is the shift amount s(n) = w(n-1) + n - 1. Solving this gives s(n) = 3*2^(n-2) - 1 for n > 1. For n = 1, let s(1) = 1. (For what it's worth, this gives [A083329](https://oeis.org/A083329) shifted by 1).

The second step, label placement, is not specified, so I made the following choice: Each node is a word in {1,2,3,4}^n. E.g., S(4, C_4) has nodes 1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1121, ..., 4444. The nodes that deserve labels are those for which the (n-1)-symbols in its name agree. So for n > 1, S(n, C_4) will have 16 labeled nodes—four to a side—and S(1, C_4) will have all four nodes labeled. I took some liberties with placement where I thought they looked decent/didn't overlap with adjacent node labels.

The third step, drawing, is easy. Using the shift amount computed in step 1, draw 4 copies of S(n-1, C_4).

Finally, we need to connect some nodes between the 4 copies. But what nodes? Fortunately, this is specified in the definition of S(n, G) (for arbitrary G). For all edges (x,y) in G, we need to add edges (xy...y, yx...x).

Now I don't know TikZ very well, so I hope experts will suggest improvements to my code. To construct this, I used the `graphs` library and constructed a graph macro.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\s@dup[2]{%
    \ifnum\numexpr#1>\@ne
        #2%
        \s@dup{#1-\@ne}{#2}%
    \fi
}
\def\s@compute@label#1#2{%
    \def\s@quad{#1}%
    \ifx#2\relax
        \def\s@temp{#1}
        \edef\s@label{[label=\s@label@pos:\s@prefix]}%
    \else
        \def\s@temp{#2}%
        \expandafter\s@check@label
    \fi
}
\def\s@check@label#1{%
    \ifx#1\relax
        \edef\s@label{[label=\s@label@pos:\s@prefix]}%
    \else\if#1\s@temp
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\s@check@label
    \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\s@mismatch
    \fi\fi
}
\def\s@mismatch#1\relax{%
    \def\s@label{}%
}
\def\s@label@pos{%
    \ifcase\numexpr4*(\s@quad-1)+\s@temp-1\relax
        south west% 11
    \or west%       12
    \or north%      13
    \or south%      14
    \or west%       21
    \or north west% 22
    \or north%      23
    \or south%      24
    \or south%      31
    \or north%      32
    \or north east% 33
    \or east%       34
    \or south%      41
    \or north%      42
    \or east%       43
    \or south east% 44
    \fi
}

\tikzgraphsset{
    level/.store in=\s@level,
    prefix/.store in=\s@prefix,
    no placement,
    level=1,
    prefix={},
    declare={sierpinski}{%
        [/utils/exec={%
                \ifnum\s@level=\z@
                    % Step 2: Figure out what to label.
                    \expandafter\s@compute@label\s@prefix\relax
                    \edef\subgraph{\s@prefix \s@label}%
                \else
                    % Step 1: Compute the shift amount.
                    \ifnum\s@level=\@ne
                        \def\s@shift{1}%
                    \else
                        \pgfmathsetmacro\s@shift{3*pow(2,\s@level-2)-1}%
                    \fi
                    \count@=\s@level\relax
                    \advance\count@\m@ne
                    \edef\subgraph{%
                        % Step 3: Draw each of the four S(n-1, C_4) shifted appropriately.
                        sierpinski [level=\the\count@, prefix=\s@prefix1, /tikz/shift={(0,0)}];%
                        sierpinski [level=\the\count@, prefix=\s@prefix2, /tikz/shift={(0,\s@shift)}];%
                        sierpinski [level=\the\count@, prefix=\s@prefix3, /tikz/shift={(\s@shift,\s@shift)}];%
                        sierpinski [level=\the\count@, prefix=\s@prefix4, /tikz/shift={(\s@shift,0)}];%
                        % Step 4:  Connect edges.
                        \s@prefix1\s@dup\s@level2 -- \s@prefix2\s@dup\s@level1;% 12...2 -- 21...1
                        \s@prefix2\s@dup\s@level3 -- \s@prefix3\s@dup\s@level2;% 23...3 -- 32...2
                        \s@prefix3\s@dup\s@level4 -- \s@prefix4\s@dup\s@level3;% 34...4 -- 43...3
                        \s@prefix4\s@dup\s@level1 -- \s@prefix1\s@dup\s@level4;% 41...1 -- 14...4
                    }%
                \fi
            },%
            parse/.expand once=\subgraph
        ]%
    }
}
\makeatother
```

Now we just need to use it!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [nodes={circle, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, fill, empty nodes}] {sierpinski [level=1]};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: S(1, C_4)]

You can change how the nodes are drawn by changing the `\graph` parameters. Changing the `level` parameter to `sierpinski` will produce S(level, C_4). Here are levels 2, 3, and 4.

[image: S(2, C_4)]
[image: S(3, C_4)]
[image: S(4, C_4)]

S(4, C_4) is large, so I added the `x` and `y` parameters to `tikzpicture` to specify the size.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2em,y=2em]
    \graph [nodes={circle, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, fill, empty nodes}] {sierpinski [level=4]};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I didn't include the "Copy 1" text because that wasn't as interesting to me, but it shouldn't be difficult to do.